# L, Z and V in Java method signature

Tags: java

I'm getting

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
```

What do `L`, `Z`, and `V` stand for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Section 4.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2) of the JVM Spec:

```
Character     Type          Interpretation
------------------------------------------
B             byte          signed byte
C             char          Unicode character
D             double        double-precision floating-point value
F             float         single-precision floating-point value
I             int           integer
J             long          long integer
L<classname>; reference     an instance of class 
S             short         signed short
Z             boolean       true or false
[             reference     one array dimension
```

Comment: +V stands for void

Answer (score 11):

These are the type signatures for primitives:

```
Type Signature                           Java Type
       V                                    void
       Z                                    boolean
       B                                    byte
       C                                    char
       S                                    short
       I                                    int
       J                                    long
       F                                    float
       D                                    double                                          
L fully-qualified-class;            fully-qualified-class
    [ type                                  type[]
```

`setFeature` takes a `String` and a `boolean` and returns `void`.